# Increment a value inside php foreach?

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

Is it possible to increment a php variable inside a foreach?
I know how to loop by declaring outside.

I'm looking for something like the syntax below

```
foreach ($some as $somekey=>$someval; $i++)
{

}
```

Comment: The above is not valid. `$i++` is not allowed within the `foreach`. Did you mix it up with `for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)` ?

Comment: s, I 'm looking for something similar.  It can save me two lines of codes

Answer (score 48):

No, you will have to use

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($some as $somekey=>$someval) {
    //xyz
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Beware if you have a `continue` statement in the loop (which could skip the increment) - in that case it might be better to start with `$i  = -1` and increment it before `//xyz`.

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach ($some as $somekey=>$someval)
{
     $i++;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

lazy way of doing is:

```
{
    $i=1;
    foreach( $rows as $row){
        $i+=1;
    }
}
```

,but you have to scope foreach for $i to dont exist after foreach or at last unset it

```
$i=1;
foreach( $rows as $row){
    $i+=1;
}
unset($i);
```

, but you should use for cycle for that as leopold wrote.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dataArray = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($_POST as $key => $data) {
    if (!empty($data['features'])) {
        $dataArray[$i]['feature'] = $data['features'];
        $dataArray[$i]['top_id'] = $data['top_id'];
        $dataArray[$i]['pro_id'] = $data['pro_id'];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old one here, but these are my thoughts to it.

```
$some = ['foo', 'bar'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($some); $i++){
 echo $some[$i];
}
```

-- **Update** --

```
$some = ['foo', 'bar'];
$someCounted = count($some);

for($i = 0; $i < $someCounted; $i++){
 echo $some[$i];
}
```

It would achieve, what you are looking for in first place.
Yet you'd have to increment your index $i.
So it would not save you any typing.

Comment: using count inside for will execute count function every loop,
dont use like that, write before loop to variable and use it later.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason not to use

```
foreach ($some as $somekey=>$someval)
{
$i++;
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($some as $somekey=>$someval)
{
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($some as $somekey=>$someval)
{
 $i++;
}
```

i is just a variable. Even though it's used to iterate over whatever item you're using, it can still be modified like any other.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick!
Remember that you'll have to define $i = 0 before the foreach loop if you want to start counting/incrementing from 0.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($some as $somekey=>$someval) {
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is **not** possible. I was looking for an elegant way to do this, very similar to this:

`for ($k = 0 ; $k < $columns; $k++){ echo '<td></td>'; }`

This works for the `for` functionality in PHP, but then you would have to pull the item, such as `$columns[$k]`, and then you're back to a less than ideal situation.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672062/php-loop-x-amount-of-times)